# How do I pass in the values to agSelectCellEditor to make it multi-select?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

The agSelectCellEditor is built on the standard select element. How do I format the data to allow multiple selections? This the format for a single selection.

```
const languageCellEditorParams = {
    values: ['English', 'Spanish', 'French', 'Portuguese', '(other)'],
};

<AgGridReact>
    <AgGridColumn field="language" cellEditor="agSelectCellEditor" cellEditorParams={languageCellEditorParams} />
</AgGridReact>
```